# Can a gMSA be used with Centralized Certificates?

Tags: active-directory, managed-service-accounts, centralized-certificates

I'm planning a rollout of IIS Centralized Certificates (on Windows 2016 servers), and attempting to determine if this would support a Group Managed Service account, or if I have to go with a regular domain or local account. I've searched for a few hours but haven't found anything definitive. I'd like to know either personal experience or an authoritative answer (from documentation, MS blog, whatever).

Comment: Every bit of documentation on the subject - including using the IIS Administration API, specifically requires a (user) name and password.  The password for a gMSA is not (technically) available to you.  Accordingly, you would be unable to specify the password in the configuration.

Comment: Other use cases for MSAs and gMSAs often have the documentation say "leave the password field blank" ... I do have a feeling you are actually correct in this instance, especially since there's no documentation describing that for CCS ... but I had to ask.

Comment: I don't have any IIS servers with this IIS feature enabled in the current environment to check; but I believe the username and password field are required to exit the menu.  I agree with the mandate to ask.  gMSAs are one of my biggest frustrations with Microsoft.  I was on board the minute the original MSAs were announced - but there was nothing that would support it and in the 10+ years there has been less-than-stellar progress (I feel) in getting them easily integrated with the "services" that I most desire their use.